# Drupal 6 Admin Links Broken

Tags: .htaccess, drupal, drupal-6

I'm trying to to upgrade a site from Drupal 7 which is going to be moved to a new server. I've moved the site to the new server, and am accessing it through the IP address. All the pages and page links work properly when viewing the site, but when I try to access any of the admin links (i.e. /admin or /admin/config), I'm redirected to the live Drupal 6 site on the old server. I've updated the htaccess file, and changed the base_url variable in the settings file. Any other recommendations? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand you. You say "I'm trying to to upgrade a site from Drupal 7" but then you say "I'm redirected to the live Drupal 6 site on the old server." Are you going from D6 on old server to D7 on new server? Or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I've seen that before, it's been due to the [Secure Pages module](http://drupal.org/project/securepages). Make sure you have the Secure Base URL and Non-secure Base URL set correctly for the new site.

Comment: Awesome! Was so confused. ha. Thanks!